# How do I get the new version of openssl to display in my phpinfo

Tags: php, apache, openssl

I updated my version of openSSL tonight but the phpinfo() still shows the old version. I restarted Apache and its still showing the old version. The update shows correctly when I check the version using Putty

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In order to update OpenSSL within PHP, you will need to recompile PHP.  By running the same configure command as before specifying `--with-openssl=/usr/include` it will link PHP to the upgraded OpenSSL library files.  Then restart Apache again and it should be showing the upgraded version.  You can try just `--with-openssl` and if it is in one of the default locations it will work.  /usr/include is also common.

Comment: Sorry, this Shell stuff is not so much my thing. I hit in --with-openssl=/usr/include and I get "no such file or dir"

Comment: In your phpinfo(), near the beginning you should see "Configure Command"  You should download the latest version of PHP, or `cd` into the directory used to build the current PHP install and run the configure command from phpinfo().  That will set up the new configuration.  Then run `make clean`, `make`, and `make install` go build and install the new version.  Now you can restart apache.

Comment: Thanks, I used the easyapache tonight to update my php to 5.3.8 after I updated the openssl. Still having the problem. So your saying I need to do this with Putty not the easyapache

Comment: You can with EA, I didn't know how it had been set up originally.  How did you update OpenSSL?  It may be that WHM is not using the OpenSSL you upgraded, or the wrong package was installed.

Comment: So if I have this command in phpinfo() 
`cscript /nologo configure.js "--enable-snapshot-build" "--enable-debug-pack" "--with-pdo-oci=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--with-oci8-12c=c:\php-sdk\oracle\x64\instantclient_12_1\sdk,shared" "--enable-object-out-dir=../obj/" "--enable-com-dotnet=shared" "--with-mcrypt=static" "--without-analyzer" "--with-pgo"`
How is possible that it shows me openSSL 1.0.21 in there?

Comment: @Čamo Because it's being loaded as a dynamic module through php.ini?

Comment: Somewhere in php.ini is "extension=php_openssl.dll" which is loading it dynamically so it didn't have to be compiled into the php binary.