# PHP Wrong OpenSSL Version

Tags: php, server, openssl

My server use OpenSSL 1.1.1 but PHP Run with 1.0.2, how to update the PHP OpenSSL?

Path of Openssl 1.1.1: `/usr/local/openssl`

Path reported from PHPINFO: `Openssl default config     /etc/pki/tls/openssl.cnf`

Apache run with:

```
Apache/2.4.37 (Unix) OpenSSL/1.1.1a configured -- resuming normal operations
```

I have recompiled the PHP but result is always the same

I give you root access of server (its a test server) or teamviewer.

[image]

If recompile with the new OpenSSL Installation 1.0.2.q i have this result:

```
OpenSSL support     enabled
OpenSSL Library Version     OpenSSL 1.0.2q 20 Nov 2018
OpenSSL Header Version  OpenSSL 1.0.2k 26 Jan 2017
Openssl default config  /usr/local/openssl/ssl/openssl.cnf
```

Header and Library not match

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I get the new version of openssl to display in my phpinfo](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7508857/how-do-i-get-the-new-version-of-openssl-to-display-in-my-phpinfo)

Comment: no... question updated..

Comment: That's less of a programming question but rather one of installing the right programs, unless of course you have programs compiling PHP yourself.

Comment: If the result is same, check the openssl path in php configure command (both the command and the things in that path). The library of version 1.0.2 won't be compiled out of void. @MarcusJ.Kennedy

Comment: The 1.0.2 is already present as soon as you install Centos 7.6 Minimal, in vain all the processes to update it, the only solution is to install a new version and compile the PHP with that version, but it does not happen because it does not change anything, once the compiling PHP always reports 1.0.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have changed OS to Fedora, Fedora 29 start with OpenSSL 1.1.1 and Repo always Updated, centos is a big s**t.